# "Unexpected column {name} in data" with multivariate time series forecast using NeuralProphet

Tags: python, pandas, neural-network

The title summarises it pretty much. After adding the additional lagged regressors to the model, it pops up an error when fitting the model. What could be the problem?

Code:

```
# 3 step ahead AR and lagged regressor model

df = df_ercot
m = NeuralProphet(
    n_forecasts=3,
    n_lags=3,
    learning_rate= 0.1,
)
m = m.add_lagged_regressor(names=regions) #, only_last_value=True)
m.highlight_nth_step_ahead_of_each_forecast(3)
metrics = m.fit(df, freq="H")
```

The error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-39259abef9ed> in <module>
      9 m = m.add_lagged_regressor(names=regions) #, only_last_value=True)
     10 m.highlight_nth_step_ahead_of_each_forecast(3)
---> 11 metrics = m.fit(df, freq="H")

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/neuralprophet/df_utils.py in normalize(df, data_params)
    381     for name in df.columns:
    382         if name not in data_params.keys():
--> 383             raise ValueError("Unexpected column {name} in data")
    384         new_name = name
    385         if name == "ds":

ValueError: Unexpected column {name} in data
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data about df ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason Neural Prophet does not like columns which are not either, 'y','ds' or a named regressor.

I have found a clean way to do this;

```
# load binned data
df = pd.read_csv('xxx.csv',parse_dates =['DateTime'])#
df = df.sort_values('DateTime')

# rename ds columns and y columns as per docs
df = df.rename(columns={'DateTime': 'ds',forecastName: 'y'})

columnsToKeep = ['ds','y']
regressorsList = ['regressor1','regressor2','regressor3']

# now the cool one liner..
# this removes all columns not 'ds','y' or any regressors
df_regressors_only = df[df.columns.intersection(np.concatenate((columnsToKeep, regressorsList)))]

m = NeuralProphet(
n_forecasts=7,
n_lags=7,
num_hidden_layers=4,
d_hidden=16)

m = m.add_lagged_regressor(names=regressorsList)
```

**You are now left with df without unused regressors.**

Comment: FYI there seems to be an problem with sub daily data. All my notebooks with 60m ‘H’ data are giving errors about missing data. Only daily ‘D’ data is working.